# Understanding the sentence in which a conjunction is omitted

Tags: sentence-meaning, conjunctions

> The paintings were discussed as an index of the democracy of a society
>   **that chose to represent its class, action, and occupations exactly as they were**, **wide-ranging realism was seen as the great
>   accomplishment of Dutch art.** [link](https://gre.kmf.com/question/52j86j.html)

Would you please explain it that why any conjunction is not written between these sentences?

Comment: There is no doubt that there is something missing. The text is wrongly punctuated or even improperly organized.

Comment: If it's going to be a single sentence, you need a semicolon here: "**... exactly as they were; wide-ranging realism ...**" — there's nothing wrong with the part you're having a problem parsing, except that it's a bit flabby and could be pared down for clarity.

Comment: In reading the linked example, it seems to be part of the writer's style, to have long (run on-ish) sentences. I found myself out of breadth reading it.